# How to write pandas dataframe, and insert image or chart into the same excel workbook, but multiple worksheets

Tags: pandas

I am have been working on the above task for a while now, but my code is not working as I expected so I would kindly like a little help from this forum. Below is the piece of code I wrote for this task:

```
###---------1st Visualization; Printing and Writing Results to An excel File 
for cust in Unique_cust_list:
    df_cust = miniBid_data[miniBid_data['Carrier_Code'] == cust]
    df_cust_lane = df_cust.groupby(['Mini_Bid_Date_2']).agg({'Lane_Id': 'sum'}).reset_index()
    df_cust_rank = df_cust.groupby(['Mini_Bid_Date_2']).agg({'Cost_Rank': 'mean'}).reset_index()
    df_cust_mer = pd.merge(df_cust_lane, df_cust_rank, how='inner', on='Mini_Bid_Date_2', copy=True)      
   figure = df_cust_rank.plot(kind='bar', x ='Mini_Bid_Date_2', y='Cost_Rank', legend=False, title=cust+" Carrier's Cost Ranking")
    fig = figure.get_figure()
    figSaved = fig.savefig(cust+'PPlot.png')

    # writing the multiple dataframes to worksheets using Pandas and XlsxWriter.
    # Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('MiniBids_multiple_Results_Sample2.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    # Write each dataframe to a different worksheet.
    df_cust_mer.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=cust, index=False)
    workbook  = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets[cust]
    ## insert the figure as image
    worksheet.insert_image('E1', 'figSaved')
    writer.save()
```

Below is also samples of my data set used:
a) "miniBid_data"
[image]

b) "df_cust_rank" - created out of "miniBid_data" for each "Carrier_Code" for the plots:
[image]

C) "df_cust_mer" - a sample dataframe from "miniBid_data" written to excelfor each "Carrier_Code":

[image]

My expectation is to have a single workbook("MiniBids_multiple_Results.xlsx") with several tabs(sheets) for each of the "Carrier_Code" alongside their DataFrame shown in "C", and respective charts plotted from DataFrame show in "B" above.

However, it seems the code has overwritten the information each time. I shall be glad for any help from the audience in this forum. Thank you in advance.

Comment: yes, the mode append doesnt exist

Comment: That's what I figured, but I am not sure how to approach the issue from here on. I would like some suggestions if you have one for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a reading of your code it seems the error is coming from your object writer

i suggest you to write you code like: (set your writer outside the loop)

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('MiniBids_multiple_Results_Sample2.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

for cust in Unique_cust_list:
     :
     :
    ## insert the figure as image
    worksheet.insert_image('E1', 'figSaved')

writer.save()
```